# Is there a way to convert between text and 8-bit binary (extended ASCII) in Python?

Tags: text, binary, python-3.9

So I'm working on a program and, as part of the program, I need to convert text to binary and binary to text. However, the binary must be 8-bit meaning 8 bits for every character.
I have looked on the internet and only found examples such as:

```
a = 'text'
a_bytes = bytes(a, "ascii")
print(' '.join(["{0:b}".format(x) for x in a_bytes]))
```

As I explained earlier, I need the binary in 8-bit/extended ASCII format but this and all other internet examples seem to convert to 7-bit/regular ASCII binary! I'm using Python 3.9.7 if it helps!
I have tried just adding a zero in front but it is then awkward to convert back to text!
Can somebody please help!

I tried:

```
a = 'text'
a_bytes = bytes(a, "ascii")
print(' '.join(["{0:b}".format(x) for x in a_bytes]))
```

It gave:

```
1110100 1100101 1110011 1110100
```

I expected:

```
01110100 01100101 01111000 01110100
```

Comment: This question seems somewhat confused. There is no difference between the ASCII for e.g. `'A'` and the extended ASCII for `'A'`. `bytes` gives a collection of bytes, not 7-bit chunks. Also do you want bytes or do you want a string in the characters `'01'` representing those bytes?

Comment: If all you want is to have a leading zero explicitly displayed you can use something like `' '.join(bin(b)[2:].zfill(8) for b in a_bytes)`. The `zfill` method will pad the string if needed by zeros on the left.

Comment: There is nothing particularly awkward in converting from a binary string with a leading `'0'` to a character. No need to strip off that 0. For example, `chr(int('01110100',2))` evaluates to the character `'t'`.